# IE11 alert after navigation begins cancels the navigation

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events, internet-explorer-11

We have some Javascript that is used for navigation when you click a tab in which the window.location is set to another URL with query string parameters.  This URL basically:

1. checks if the user is logged in
2. If they are not, redirect them to an error page to login again
3. If they are, logs them out and continues to the next step
4. redirects them to another url of another system which then logs them in to that system

If the next system is taking some time completing the request, the browser is sitting there with the loading icon, and the user may get impatient and click the tab again.  If they do, step 1 is done a second time, and now that they are logged out from the initial processing of step 1.2, they fail the check and end up following the path of 1.1.

The workaround we put in place is pretty simple.  We put the window.location into an IF statement that checks if a person has already clicked on a tab and navigation has already been kicked off.  If not, then it does the window.location setting.  If so, then we call "alert('Please be patient');".  This seems to work fine for every browser except for IE11, and even then, only when <kbd>F12</kbd> dev console is not open.  If you have it open, it works fine.

But if you don't, for some reason the alert popup ends up cancelling the navigation, and the page never goes anywhere.  Almost the same as if you pressed escape, or clicked the "Stop" button.  There's also sometimes this weird scenario where the next page loads, but it thinks that the alert window is still open, but it's not.  I can see the extra task in task manager, but it's not visible.

Has anybody heard or seen anything like this?  **Please note**, I know there are other ways of handling this situation other than using an alert.  I'm not looking for suggestions about how to accomplish a message in a different manner.  I'm more interested in finding out if there's any decent documentation that could explain to me why an alert after the page has started to unload may be behaving this way in IE11, and only when <kbd>F12</kbd> isn't open.

*EDIT Adding code Example*

```
var navigatingTo;
function doNavigation(destination){
  if (navigatingTo && navigatingTo != ""){
    alert(navigatingTo);
  } else {
    navigatingTo = "Please be patient\nNavigating to " + destination;
    window.location = "/somepage.aspx?d=" + destination;
  }
}
```

Comment: Code would have been far more useful than that wall of text, but from what i've read so far, it sounds like you have a rogue console.log() somewhere that's causing IE to choke when the console isn't open.

Comment: Added code sample.  There's no console.log anywhere.  And there's no errors in the console when I do open up F12 after it's been cancelled.